# shutil.copy() throwing up invalid argument error when repeating

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

I'm seeing some very odd behavior with shutil's copy method.

Here is my basic code:

```py
def time_and_log(func):
    def inner_function(*args,**kwargs):
        times = np.array([])
        repititions = kwargs.pop("repititions",1)
        for i in range(repititions):
            print(f"i: {i}")
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            logfile = func(*args,**kwargs)
            end_time = time.perf_counter()
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
            times = np.append(times,elapsed_time)
            #Other stuff ommitted here, but basically just logging to a file
    return inner_function

@time_and_log
def copy(src,dst,logfile,repititions=1):
    if Path(src).is_dir():
        shutil.copytree(src,dst)
    else:
        #I originally didn't have this but I thought the existence of the file was blocking it somehow?
        if os.path.isfile(dst):
            os.remove(dst)
        shutil.copy(src,dst)
    return logfile
```

the time_and_log decorator just takes the number of repetitions and loops it that many times and then does some custom formatting and logging.

I'm writing to a mounted file system via WSL2, the first iteration of the loop it runs, fine, then the second iteration of the loop returns an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\wsl.localhost\\\\Ubuntu\\\\home\\\\me\\\\mountpoint\\\\myfile.bin'
```

But then I can take that exact argument and do this:

```py
shutil.copy(src,'\\\\wsl.localhost\\\\Ubuntu\\\\home\\\\me\\\\mountpoint\\\\myfile.bin')
```

and that works.

I'm kind of baffled. Anyone know why this is happening?

Here's the code to recreate it

```
LOG_FILE = "log.txt"
REPS = 5
dst = r"\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\me\\mountpoint\\"
src_path = ".\\anypath\\"
test_file = "myfile.bin"

copy(src=src_path+test_file,dst=dst+test_file,logfile=LOG_FILE,repititions=REPS)
```

For clarity, the reason I'm doing this is I'm testing performance for different methods to mount to azure storage, blobfuse vs smb file share vs NFSv3 vs RClone

Comment: "the time_and_log decorator just takes the number of repetitions and loops it that many times and then does some custom formatting and logging." **Can you reproduce the problem without it**? Is it simply a consequence of running the same `copy` code repeatedly, or does something else happen in your decorator that relates to the problem? Please: a) read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]; and b) don't reinvent the wheel without a good reason - the standard library provides the `timeit` and `logging` modules for these purposes.

Comment: Once you have a proper MRE, please also show a corresponding, [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting **starting from the line that says** `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: Honestly dude, I have been trying to create a pure and simple MRE for the last 45 minutes and I can't. If you know a lot about WSL2 and blobfuse and shutil please let me know your thoughts. If you don't maybe lets just leave it for someone who does. I'll spend more time trying to come up with an MRE but it won't be faithful unless someone else is using an Ubuntu WSL2 mounted cloud file system.

Comment: I'm just explaining how the site works. Even if someone could guess what the problem is from experience, without a MRE, that doesn't leave behind a question that is searchable and can help others. "it won't be faithful unless someone else is using an Ubuntu WSL2 mounted cloud file system." It's not clear to me why you believe that this is relevant to the problem. Have you tried the code (with appropriately modified file paths) on other systems?

Comment: Goodness. You embody the reason why people hate on SO. Condescending, unhelpful. "just explaining how the site works", I do understand how it works. and I am telling you I am trying my absolute utmost to adhere. If you can't help please leave this alone.

Comment: And yes I tried with local to local and it works fine.